# Ruby: how to find out if an object is a singleton

Tags: ruby, singleton

The Ruby docs document for [Object#singleton_class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class):

> Returns the singleton class of *obj*. This method creates a new
>   singleton class if *obj* does not have one.

Hence, (despite some comments) an object does **not always** have a singleton class. In the following I call an object *a singleton* if this object has a singleton class.

A newly created object does not have a singleton class, and therefore is not a singleton:

```
a = "string"                     # => "string"          # not (yet) a singleton
b = String.new("another one")    # => "another one"     # not (yet) a singleton
[a.class, b.class]               # => [String, String]
```

An object becomes a singleton only after the definition of a singleton method,

```
def a.greet
  "hello"
end
```

or after a singleton class is created due to a class variable being defined to the singleton class of the object

```
class << b
  @var = 42
end
```

Unfortunately, in Ruby a call of the *class* method does not reveal if the object is a singleton because for singletons the method does not return the actual (singleton) class but the class used for creation of the object:

```
[a.class, b.class]  # => [String, String]
```

Merely a call to *Marshal.dump* unveils if the object is actually a singleton:

```
Marshal.dump(a, $stdout)
# TypeError: singleton can't be dumped

Marshal.dump(b, $stdout)
# TypeError: singleton can't be dumped
```

Is there any other, more elegant way to find out if an object is a singleton?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Every object in Ruby always has a singleton class. Every object in Ruby is always the singleton instance of its singleton class. What, *precisely* do you mean by "object is a singleton"? What is your precise definition of "being a singleton"?

Comment: Furthermore, you can simply use `"a".singleton_class`

Comment: Do you mean given the method `m = a.method(:greet)` you want to know if it is defined on a singleton class? If so, `m.owner.singleton_class? #=> true`, whereas `class C; def greet; end; end; C.new.method(:greet).owner.singleton_class #=> false?`  See [Module#singleton_class?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-singleton_class-3F). (@Jörg, please comment on the logic.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have clarified my question.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Yes, I can. But it would create a singleton class if not yet existing. I don't want to create one. I just want to know if the object already has one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good point, thx. I have clarified my question. One possible partial answer could be to look for *Object#singleton_methods* : works for object *a* as long as the methods are not private. But there is no similar way to look for instance variables in the singleton class (look at object *b*) because we first need a reference to the singleton class itself.

Comment: "But it would create a singleton class if not yet existing. I don't want to create one. I just want to know if the object already has one." – Every object always has a singleton class in Ruby. Some Ruby implementations may or may not delay the physical creation of this singleton class until and unless you are actually looking at it, but that is a private internal implementation detail of a specific version of a specific Ruby implementation, and there is no guarantee that will be the case on a different Ruby implementation or even a different version. Logically, it is always there.

Comment: The implementation will make sure that whenever you try to look at the singleton class, there will be a singleton class, and when you are not looking at the singleton class, then you cannot possibly know whether it is there, so logically, from your point of view, it is always there. Just like when you look at `1`, you see an object, even though in every single currently existing Ruby implementation, it is not implemented as one; it is not implemented like all other objects at all, but completely differently.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So, the cited error message of *Marshal.dump*s *TypeError* is wrong? What would be the correct error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am updating this answer after some additional research.  Thanks to [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) for his insightful answer to my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644285/inspecting-marshal-methods).

You can employ two singleton methods to determine whether an object contains a "substantial" singleton that would prevent it from being marshaled.

```
a = "string-a"
b = "string-b"
c = "string-c"

def a.greet
  "hello"
end

class << b
  @var = 42
end

def no_substantial_singleton?(obj)
  obj.singleton_class.instance_methods(false).empty? &&
  obj.singleton_class.instance_variables.empty?
end

def marshal_if_possible(obj)
    puts Marshal.dump(obj) if no_substantial_singleton?(obj)
end

marshal_if_possible(a) #=>
marshal_if_possible(b) #=>
marshal_if_possible(c) #=> 'string-c:ET'
```

Comment: Right. This works for the object `a` from my question. But unfortunately not for the object `b`.

Comment: Hello Min-Soo.  I have updated my answer and addressed the issue with object b.

Comment: For some extended object, I used `.singleton_methods` and `.instance_variables`.